# Splitting columns and reformat date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an object, `slist` that I need to split, reformat the date, and export as a tab delimited file. For the splitting I think I'm tripping up understanding the first row? Here is `slist`:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=slist) 
newdf['datetime','values'] = df['node_21_Depth_above_invert'].astype(str).str.split('  ',expand=True)
```

Which gives me something like this:

[image]

I've spent a ton of time trying to figure this out and I know there are a lot of other pandas questions about column splitting, but I've hit a wall and any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what is the type of `slist` (string, list, ...)? Could you add (avoid images) the output of `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: `print(df.head(5).to_dict())
{'node_21_Depth_above_invert': {Timestamp('1998-01-01 01:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('1998-01-01 02:00:00'): 1.519419550895691, Timestamp('1998-01-01 03:00:00'): 2.0, Timestamp('1998-01-01 04:00:00'): 2.0, Timestamp('1998-01-01 05:00:00'): 2.0}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you now have the datetime as row index, you can make it a data column by [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then rename the columns, as follows:

```
newdf = df.reset_index()
newdf.columns = ['datetime','values']
```

---

**Test Data Preparation**

```
slist = {'node_21_Depth_above_invert': {pd.Timestamp('1998-01-01 01:00:00'): 1.0, pd.Timestamp('1998-01-01 02:00:00'): 1.519419550895691, pd.Timestamp('1998-01-01 03:00:00'): 2.0, pd.Timestamp('1998-01-01 04:00:00'): 2.0, pd.Timestamp('1998-01-01 05:00:00'): 2.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=slist)

print(df)

                     node_21_Depth_above_invert
1998-01-01 01:00:00                     1.00000
1998-01-01 02:00:00                     1.51942
1998-01-01 03:00:00                     2.00000
1998-01-01 04:00:00                     2.00000
1998-01-01 05:00:00                     2.00000
```

**Run New Codes**

```
newdf = df.reset_index()
newdf.columns = ['datetime','values']
```

**Result:**

```
print(newdf)

             datetime   values
0 1998-01-01 01:00:00  1.00000
1 1998-01-01 02:00:00  1.51942
2 1998-01-01 03:00:00  2.00000
3 1998-01-01 04:00:00  2.00000
4 1998-01-01 05:00:00  2.00000
```